# Python Regular Expression Clobbering Text Between Multiple Latex Expression Matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean conversational text from a StackExchange corpus which contains sentences which may have Latex expressions inside. Latex expressions are delimited by the $ sign: For instance $y = ax + b$

Here is a line of example text from the data containing multiple Latex expressions:

@Gruber - this is another example, when applied like so: $\mathrm{Var} \left(X^2\right) = 4 X^2 \mathrm{Var} (X)$ doesn't make any sense, on the left side you have a constant and on the right a random variable. Did you mean $4E(X)^2 Var(X)$ bless those that take the road less travelled. Another exception in your theory is $4E(X)^2 Var(X)$. What were you thinking? :)

Here is what I have so far: It seems to clobber text between each Latex Expression match and gives one huge match which is incorrect.

```
([\$](.*)[\$]){1,3}?
```

Comment: Try to replace the `.` by `[^$]`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, tried with [^$] and [^\$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you put `{1,3}` at the end, what goal did you try to achieve. Anyway, your mistake is that you use `[\$]`, which gives you a set of two characters - a backslash and a dollar. I suggest you use

```
\$([^$]*)\$
```

and replace it with an empty string: [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/2xNTzX/2/)

Comment: Hey Alex, perfect answer thank you. I wanted to try the Ungreedy evaluation hence experimenting with the {1,3}. I appreciate your helpp very much, thanks